# Asus Geforce GT 640 1GB GDDR5 Dual Monitor Setup

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have been searching throughout the internet without success of finding out about this.

The main question is: Can my graphics card support dual monitor on different display ports? (1 on VGA, and 1 on DVI for example)

Also, if they can, do the monitors have to be the same size or can they vary in size as my desk is quite small and I don't have enough room for a bigger desk.

My current desktop resolution is a 1440x900 (16:10 or 8:5)

Here it says my graphics card can support it: 
http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt640/specifications

So that's not a problem.

Comment: Hi Dominik, welcome to Super User. To answer your question... yes? (How would it support dual monitors from the same port?) They don't need to be the same size: http://i.imgur.com/506z8l0.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please clarify your seemingly contradictory statement *"it says my graphics card can support it...So that's not a problem."*  What exactly are you pointing out your graphics card can support?

Comment: It can support dual monitors, but I don't know if it is possible to do it with one monitor connected to the VGA slot and one to the DVI slot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this card DOES support and you can use whatever connections you like. The monitors doesn't have to be of the same size, but there is a upper limit of the resolution. You're ok with 2x 1440x900, and I think you're ok even with 2x 1920x1080 if you use only the digital connections.

Comment: So it should work if I have one monitor connected to HDMI and one to the DVI slot?

Comment: Yeah, that should do the trick. Even if you use the DVI or HDMI and the VGA it will work, but maybe you will not be able to use 2x 1920x1080.

Comment: I'm honestly not bothered about a 1920x1080 screen resolution, plus I don't have enough desk space for one. And let me get this straight then: HDMI + DVI = Works - HDMI + VGA = Works? - DVI + VGA = Not sure about this one. Sorry, I just really want to make sure I make the right decision.